# Failed to connect to bitbucket.org port 443: No route to host

Tags: git, bitbucket

I am getting error as **Failed to connect to bitbucket.org port 443: No route to host** when i try to pull or push.
The same repositories are available to pull push outside our network.
What could be the problem as it was working properly.

Comment: There's something wrong with your network or Internet connection. This isn't a programming problem, and is off-topic.

Comment: Offtopic, but this hint might help: check your proxy settings.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I also got same issue.

I tried to update git by ppa, Reset .gitconfig,i checked github repo is getting clone but not bitbucket, i unset http and https proxy, restarted my network services(type in terminal - 'my network services'), changed the network that my laptop was connected. But none of this work for me.

I **fixed it** by adding below line to `hosts`(/etc/hosts) file

```
104.192.143.2 bitbucket.org
```

Another solutions i didn't tried are -

Using proxy for cloning git, Connecting to Bitbucket using ssh through proxy.

This solution will also work for the below error:

> Failed to connect to bitbucket.org port 443: Network is unreachable

Comment: how about for linux platform?

Comment: I am using Linux mint 17.x

Comment: This solution fixed the issue for me on ubuntu 14.04  Thanks Rohan

Comment: 2020: Bitbucket has changed their IPs since 2018. The new ones can be found here (https://bitbucket.org/blog/new-ip-addresses-bitbucket-cloud). I'm using the IPv6 one: 2406:da00:ff00::0/96*

Comment: In my case added 104.192.141.1 bitbucket.org
I checked the IP Address from another machine.

Answer (score 7):

**UPDATE: 28-08-2018**

This is **Temp** fix but at least working for me after bitbucket new IP's

Note:- `hosts` file can be found in windows at `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc` and in Linux it exists at `/etc/hosts`. make sure you edit with admin rights i.e in windows open notepad as administrator and then open host file. In linux `sudo gedit /etc/hosts` from terminal from any location :)

for all new users or existing users who previously edited `etc/hosts` file and now stopped working just replace the old IP address of bitbucket with new one i.e in `etc/hosts`

REPLACE 
`104.192.143.3  bitbucket.org`

TO
`18.205.93.0    bitbucket.org`

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Recommendation 1:**  Just remove your origin and set the origin again, then try to push/pull. Hopefully, it will work.

```
 git remote -v
 git remote remove origin
 git remote add origin https://habibbd@bitbucket.org/ocplbd/bida-oss.git
```

**Recommendation 2:**   Remove those of lines from `Windows/System32/drivers/etc/hosts` if any one of these lines is available.

```
 104.192.143.1 bitbucket.org
 104.192.143.2 bitbucket.org
 18.205.93.0 bitbucket.org
```

**Recommendation 3:** Change the network connection/provider. Sometimes your network provider causes this kind of issue.

**Recommendation 4:**  Check firewall settings. Sometimes it was the issue for showing this kind of error.

Answer (score 0):

just restart your network connection. in ubuntu linux: sudo service network-manager restart. check if you're now connected to the internet by pinging some known websites like: ping yahoo.com or bitbucket.org

Answer (score 0):

I tried replacing the bitbucket.org with ip of server i.e 104.192.143.2 
in the source url of repo ,
git@bitbucket.org:xyz/xyz.git to git@104.192.143.2:xyz/xyz.git
And this worked while cloning repo on plesk server