# Failed to connect to bitbucket.org port 443: Network is unreachable

Tags: bitbucket

Iam getting the following issue while trying to clone the repository.

fatal: unable to access 'https://Tejaswikatha@bitbucket.org/activecubs_angularjs/activecubs-admin-angularjs.git/': Failed to connect to bitbucket.org port 443: Network is unreachable

Comment: Hope this help : [bitbucket error](https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issues/12184/failed-to-connect-to-bitbucketorg-port-443)

Comment: possible duplicate of [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38606443/failed-to-connect-to-bitbucket-org-port-443-network-is-unreachable)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to connect to bitbucket.org port 443: Network is unreachable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38606443/failed-to-connect-to-bitbucket-org-port-443-network-is-unreachable)

Answer (score 1):

For UBUNTU:

1. Open /etc/hosts file
2. Add 104.192.143.3 bitbucket.org as a first line and save file

Now cloning will work.

Answer (score 0):

This may be caused by known issues trying to `git push`, `pull`, `clone` over [IPv6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6).

You can force [IPv4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4) by adding the following line to your [hosts file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)) (`/etc/hosts` on Linux, `c:\windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` on Windows):

```
104.192.143.1 bitbucket.org
```

In you have a newer git client (>2.8), you can also force IPv4 via the `-4` or `--ipv4` switch.