# Mingw+msys2 : Failed to connect to bitbucket.org : Network is unreachable

Tags: git, ffmpeg, mercurial, bitbucket, git-clone

I want to build ffmpeg under windows 8.1 by using [this script](https://github.com/jb-alvarado/media-autobuild_suite) and last version of Mingw+Msys2 , but it gets error for any hg clone from bitbucket.org , e.g:

> $ hg clone https://bitbucket.org/multicoreware/x265
>
> abort: error:Network is unreachable

After searching on the Internet I saw [this page](https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issues/12184/failed-to-connect-to-bitbucketorg-port-443) and realized it is because that bitbucket.org has IPv6 and I can not access to it .
Please see results of the following commands:

```
$ ping -n 10 bitbucket.org

Pinging bitbucket.org [104.192.143.2] with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.

Ping statistics for 104.192.143.2:
    Packets: Sent = 10, Received = 0, Lost = 10 (100% loss),



$ ping -n 10 -6 bitbucket.org
Ping request could not find host bitbucket.org. Please check the name and try again


$ tracert bitbucket.org

Tracing route to bitbucket.org [104.192.143.1]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  192.168.1.1
  2    30 ms    29 ms     9 ms  81.12.120.2
  3    20 ms    40 ms    12 ms  81.12.120.1
  4     6 ms     8 ms    10 ms  192.168.8.41
  5    21 ms    24 ms    19 ms  192.168.8.1
  6     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  7    52 ms    56 ms    54 ms  192.168.170.241
  8    35 ms    25 ms     *     10.10.53.61
  9    27 ms    32 ms    32 ms  10.201.47.142
 10    30 ms    44 ms    38 ms  10.201.42.117
 11    40 ms    33 ms    67 ms  10.201.147.242
 12    46 ms    38 ms    59 ms  85.132.90.201
 13     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 14     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 15     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 16     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  ...
```

**NOTE :** Also, I've seen some posts on the stackoverflow.com like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38606443/failed-to-connect-to-bitbucket-org-port-443-network-is-unreachable/38606704?noredirect=1#comment75955866_38606704). But it seems works only for Linux, Because I added 104.192.143.2 bitbucket.org to my /etc/hosts but not worked.

Please guide me.

Comment: Replace bitbucket.org with the IP in `build/media-suite_compile.sh`

Comment: @Mulvya, Thanks for your comment, but it is not worked.

Comment: Switch to a mirror: `http://hg.videolan.org/x265/`

Comment: @Mulvya Thanks,yes it is a workaround , please see [this](https://github.com/jb-alvarado/media-autobuild_suite/issues/546),But I hope that Bitbucket problem will also be solved , because libgme has not an updated mirror.(at least I can't find)

Comment: @MitraM If you are connecting from Iran, you can use a proxy server for connecting to the bitbucket.org.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not an IPv6 issue - you'd have the full [2401:1d80:1010::150] address in your `ping -6` if that were the case.

Instead, it looks like you're connecting from Iran (81.12.120.0/24 is owned by an Iranian ISP). Since the US government has imposed sanctions on Iran, and since Bitbucket's infrastructure is in the US, the Bitbucket servers are required to drop requests from Iran.

Comment: Ah, now I understand the problem,
Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: unfortunately I also like the most of Iranians am victim of politics and politicians in my country and some other countries , most of the websites of the world are blocked by the government of Iran .

Comment: And when we using a proxy/VPN for pass the filter , will face to some constraints by US government.