# Git stopped working on particular system

Tags: git, bitbucket

I am using git from last few months on ubuntu and it was working fine. But now suddenly it stopped working. I can not pull / push code and get below error

```
fatal: unable to access 'git url'
Failed to connect to bitbucket.org port 443: No route to host
```

I tried to make new clone. but same error. Then I tried on another system it works fine. Clone / pull / push works fine on other system but not on mine.

Comment: Well, it says "no route to host", do you have network connection there? Can you open a browser on that machine and navigate to bitbucket.org?

Comment: Check your network connection. What happens when you type `ping bitbucket.org`? Are you behind a firewall?

Comment: Please ensure you have DNS configured for your network connection.

Comment: Lasse V. Karlsen  Yes I can navigate to bitbucket.org

Comment: @ Code-Apprentice  Got response on ping

Comment: It is a network+security issue. Even if ping will response OK, still the SSH pory may be blocked. Better check with ``telnet bitbucket.org 443`` command.

Comment: @ yorammi                                                                                                           
Trying 104.192.143.2...
Connected to bitbucket.org.
Escape character is '^]'.

Comment: You can see:[failed-to-connect-to-bitbucket-org-port-443-network-is-unreachable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38606443/failed-to-connect-to-bitbucket-org-port-443-network-is-unreachable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got same issue.

I tried to update git by ppa, Reset .gitconfig,i checked github repo is getting clone but not bitbucket, i unset http and https proxy, restarted my network services(type in terminal - 'my network services'), changed the network that my laptop was connected. But none of this work for me.

i got fixed by adding below line to hosts(/etc/hosts) file

```
138.197.154.33 bitbucket.org
```

Another solutions i didn't tried are

using proxy for cloning git, Connecting to Bitbucket using ssh through proxy.

This solution will also work for the below error:

```
Try first git push -u origin master
Then git pull origin master
```

Comment: When I added 138.197.154.33 bitbucket.org in /etc/hosts. on git clone get error as  **SSL: certificate subject name (stage.2klic.io) does not match target host name 'bitbucket.org'**

Comment: @hrishi it's just example ip address 
you please try your bitbucket ip

Comment: Done. adding ip bitbucket.org in  /etc/hosts worked for me. Thanks.