# Trying to push code to bitbucket

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

I am trying to push the code to BitBucket using `git push origin master`.

I'm getting this error:

> fatal: unable to access 'https://amitattri@bitbucket.org/wadhwarahul92/gps-riders-rails.git/': Failed to connect to bitbucket.org port 443: Network is unreachable.

Please help me out to resolve this problem.

Comment: have you checked this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38606443/failed-to-connect-to-bitbucket-org-port-443-network-is-unreachable

Comment: Yes I tried but got this error:- * Couldn't find host bitbucket.org in the .netrc file; using defaults
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 104.192.143.3...
*   Trying 2401:1d80:1010::150...
* connect to 2401:1d80:1010::150 port 443 failed: Network is unreachable
* Failed to connect to bitbucket.org port 443: Network is unreachable
* Closing connection 0
fatal: unable to access 'https://bitbucket.org/bitbucket/do_not_delete/': Failed to connect to bitbucket.org port 443: Network is unreachable

Comment: failed to connect seems to be internet firewall issue.

Comment: may be proxy issue..try bypassing proxy

Comment: @RahulWadhwa Try to clear DNS cache `ipconfig /flushdns`