# Bitbucket 443 Network is unreachable on different network

Tags: git, bitbucket

My git and Bitbucket connects and works just fine when I am in my office connected my laptop to wifi.

But when I get home and connect same laptop to my wifi and try to access bitbucket I get 443 error.

```
git pull
fatal: unable to access 'https://xxxxx@bitbucket.org/xxxx/xxxx.git/': Failed to connect to bitbucket.org port 443: Network is unreachable
```

Answer (score 7):

Added bitbucket ip to hosts file and its working now!!

```
sudo nano /etc/hosts
104.192.143.2 bitbucket.org
sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart
```

Comment: Great! Don't forget to read http://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote and http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE: 28-08-2018**

This is **Temp** fix but at least working for me after bitbucket new IP's as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38480098/failed-to-connect-to-bitbucket-org-port-443-no-route-to-host/52074610#52074610)

Note:- `hosts` file can be found in windows at `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc` and in Linux it exists at `/etc/hosts`. make sure you edit with admin rights i.e in windows open notepad as administrator and then open host file. In linux `sudo gedit /etc/hosts` from terminal from any location :)

for all new users or existing users who previously edited `etc/hosts` file and now stopped working just replace the old IP address of bitbucket with new one i.e in `etc/hosts`

REPLACE 
`104.192.143.3  bitbucket.org`

TO
`18.205.93.0    bitbucket.org`

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In centos Please allow 443 port in Firewall(tcp_in and tcp_out).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Recommendation 1:**  Just remove your origin and set the origin again, then try to push/pull. Hopefully, it will work for you.

```
 git remote -v
 git remote remove origin
 git remote add origin https://habibus@bitbucket.org/ocplbd/bida-oss.git
```

**Recommendation 2:**   Remove those of lines from `Windows/System32/drivers/etc/hosts` if any one of these lines is available.

```
 104.192.143.1 bitbucket.org
 104.192.143.2 bitbucket.org
 18.205.93.0 bitbucket.org
```

**Recommendation 3:** Switch the network connection/provider. Sometimes your network provider/connection causes for this kind of issue.

**Recommendation 4:**  Check the firewall settings. Sometimes it was the issue for giving this kind of error.

**Recommendation 5:** Check your git version and then run the following command to upgrade. Sometimes git version is the issue for showing this kind of error.

```
 sudo add-apt-repository ppa:git-core/ppa
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get install git
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [this issue](https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issues/12184/failed-to-connect-to-bitbucketorg-port-443), try and set GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 before executing the git clone: you might have more clues.

The standard advice is:

> "Failed to connect" errors could be anything from DNS issues to local network problems to ISPs that are incompletely routing Bitbucket traffic.
>   Unfortunately, there isn't enough detail in any of these comments to diagnose the exact problems, which may or may not be related to each other.
>
> If you could, please open a support ticket with the results of the following commands:
>
> For OS X, Linux, and other UNIX-based operating systems:

```
ping -c10 bitbucket.org
ping6 -c10 bitbucket.org
traceroute bitbucket.org
traceroute6 bitbucket.org
GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 git ls-remote https://bitbucket.org/bitbucket/do_not_delete
```

> For Windows:

```
ping -n 10 bitbucket.org
ping -n 10 -6 bitbucket.org
tracert bitbucket.org
tracert -6 bitbucket.org
```

(To clarify: "`ping6`" and "`traceroute6`" are the `IPv6` equivalents of "`ping`" and "`traceroute`", respectively, and "`GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1`" before any git command will detail all the HTTP-specific parts of the connection.
On the Windows side of things, the "`-6`" in the command line specifies that your computer should use `IPv6` for the `ping` or `tracert`.)

> Additionally, if you suspect that your problem is related to Bitbucket's IPv6 support, then you should be able to test your overall IPv6 connectivity by opening the following links in your browser:

```
https://ipv6.google.com
https://www.v6.facebook.com
```

> Those links should not work at all if your IPv6 connection is disabled or misconfigured.
>   If that's the case, as a *temporary* workaround (note the heavy emphasis on the word "temporary"!), you can add "`104.192.143.3 bitbucket.org`" to your hostfile while you work with your network administrators and/or ISP to fix IPv6 access on that system.